# Different approaches to override one property in an object and return a new object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For a React state variable which is an object, I need to update one property in an object and return a new object. I'm comparing the following approaches:

```
setFormData(Object.assign({}, formData, {b: 22}));
```

vs.

```
setFormData((prevData) => ({
            ...prevData,
            b: 22
        }));
```

Another possible option is, without using the arrow function,

```
setFormData( { ...prevData, "b": 22 } )
```

Are all of these valid, and is there a reason to use one vs. the other?

Comment: That's not a direct comparison - one appears to be creating a new object from the closed-over (and maybe stale) value, whereas the other uses the callback form which receives a fresh value. That's much more important than spreading vs. `Object.assign` (which the spread may be transpiled to anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches you've mentioned are valid, and they accomplish the same goal of updating a property in a React state variable, ensuring immutability.

However, the second approach with the spread operator inside a functional update is generally considered more modern and is commonly used in React because:

- The second approach is often considered more concise and readable, especially when dealing with multiple properties or nested objects.
- The functional update form is consistent with the recommended pattern for updating state based on the previous state, which is important when dealing with asynchronous state updates.

Comment: And what would be different about just doing `setFormData( { ...prevData, "b": 22 } )` without the arrow function?

Comment: This is a shorthand form of the second approach. It directly uses the spread operator to create a new object. It is concise and can be a good choice if you don't need additional logic inside the functional update. @geneb.